# Remove a revision in TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I know this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958158/remove-a-revision-in-tortoisehg-and-mercurial) has been asked and I know it´s against version control. But we have done some minor changes in the layout etc. and would like to remove the history of 30 revisions.

Is it possible to just remove these 30 revisions or merge them into one revision?

Like 160 was the last big one and then now we are on 195 but the 35 in beetween are all relatively small css changes so not really necessary for us. Is it possible to just get them into like 161 and then go from there?

Comment: What negative impact those 35 changes have on your work, or your repository?

Comment: not a big impact but i just want one checked in as css changes and therefore it would make sense to fold them all in one or not?

Comment: I guess its a matter of preferences, but to me toying around with a repo's history is rarely a good idea. I can agree with the fact that 35 consecutive changes to a css file could be folded together, but if it does not make any difference in the end when you retrieve the repo, why go through the hassle of changing the history? Especially if you have pushed your changes.

Comment: @Laf: I disagree.  Commits are logical, not physical.  A commit encapsulates a single coherent change; "coherent" in the sense that it takes the codebase from a (mostly-)functional state to another (mostly-)functional state.  Sometimes, however, the actual changes you made are interwoven and messy.  At the very least, this makes it harder to use `hg bisect` effectively, since you won't know which part of the offending commit was responsible for the breakage.  I prefer to reorganize my history before pushing.

Comment: @Kevin I disagree with your point, but this is personal preferences. But if you end up having to modify your history to cope with unwanted amount of changes in your repo, then I believe you are doing something wrong. Maybe one should consider developping such changes in a [local] branch, or stop commiting every 2-lines changes during a very active work on a specific file.

Comment: @Laf: I usually like to let my changes "cook" for a few days before pushing, so I can catch bugs and fix them without an "oops" commit.  History editing is very handy for this.  I must admit, however, I prefer to use `hg record` at the time of the commit when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find using hg revert -r REV is a much easier approach that using histedit.

**Don't do this if you have already pushed your changes.**

Observe that the changesets that are being merged are all 'draft' phases.

[image: Intial State]

1. Update to parent of the first changeset in set of changes you want to fold.

[image: Update to parent of first change set that you want to fold]

2. "hg revert -r REV -all" (where rev is the last change you want to fold) (ie. the tip  - if its not the tip then you will have to do a rebase step between step 3 and step 4).

[image]

3. Commit.

[image: Commit all the changeset as one change]

4. Use strip to remove old changesets

[image: Using the Strip command]

And the final result:

[image: Finished result]

It would be really nice to be able to do step 2 directly from the thg gui but I haven't found a way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop the revisions *and all their descendants*, you can just enable the `strip` extension, then right click->modify history->strip the changesets.

If you'd prefer to fold them together, *and you haven't pushed yet*, you can do this:

1. Enable the `histedit` extension in TortiseHG's settings.
2. Open a terminal with the terminal button.
3. Type `hg histedit 160` and press enter.  Replace 160 with the appropriate revision number.  This part may take several seconds, so don't panic if the terminal seems to freeze.
4. A text editor window will open with a list of the changes since 160.  Change the text in front of each line you want to merge from `pick` to `fold`, to combine that changeset with the one above it.  You'll also be prompted to edit the commit message after each fold.  You can use `drop` to remove the changesets instead of folding them.

If you have pushed, modifying history is more complicated; see [hg phases](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/phases) for details.

Comment: Hi Kevin thanks for the quick answer. I think the folding is what i look for. I just need them all to be in one revision beacause I just want to book it in as one revision aka css changes